# Can GPUs be dynamically allocated in a 20 GPU server?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system

The purpose for this server is deep learning algorithms. What I am planning to do is to assemble a server with 20 GPUs (Nvidia GTX 1080 TIs) and 2 CPUs (Intel Xeon Phis) and then have many users draw processing power from it.

Relevant to this question: If a user wants, say, 8 GPUs, then can 8 random free GPUs be allocated to them?

Also, in general, will this work? I still don't understand how the OS will function in this scenario. Is there some special server OS (such as Ubuntu server) which I can use to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: One server with 20 GPUs? Or a cluster of machines with GPUs?

Comment: @Sven one server with 20 GPUs, not a cluster. This is the rack: https://www.supermicro.com.tw/products/superblade/module/SBI-7128RG-F2.cfm

Comment: You got that wrong. This is a [blade system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_server). Each of the blades is a separate computer, they just share infratructure like power supply and network.

Comment: @Sven ah. That explains most of my confusion. I've actually scrapped this idea and have planned out a rack with 6 different machines each complete with 8 GPUs, and they are all linked through Infiniband network cards.

Comment: My suggestion would be to hire an expert consultant who can help you analyze your workload and come up with a good solution. HPC computing is tricky and it's easy to invest into the wrong kind of setup for your use case.

Comment: @Sven hmm that is worth considering. Also, on insidehpc.com it was written- "A high performance computer appropriate for most small and medium-sized businesses today is built from what are basically many ordinary computers connected together with a network and centrally coordinated by some **special software.**" Is this 'special software' slurm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59224/discussion-between-mythic-cocoa-and-sven).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat. And yes, slurm would be one example of such a software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not one computer but multiple ones that are each separate (but possibly connected with a fast/low latentcy Infiniband network). You need a classic HPC cluster environment with a job scheduler/batch system, eg. slurm.